# Использование VideoView и ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, videoview, exoplayer

Используя, что Video View, что ExoPlayer, не выходит загрузить видео, используя путь к нему. Путь для представления:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ScreenRecorder/Screenrecorder-2020-07-28-19-45-56-546.mp4
```

Пробовал этот путь привести к uri с помощью Uri.fromFile() и Uri.Builder(). Видео также не запускалось. Работало только на эмуляторах. У меня есть Uri этого файла (получил из intent'а), но этот файл потом будет отправлен в другую папку, и воссоздать uri с помощью методов, описанных выше, не вариант (видео не запускается, используя приведение выше).

Основная задача: найти видео -> переместить видео в папку приложения -> открывая чат, не выгружать видео из сети, а открывать его, используя путь к нему

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Может ошибка в моих действиях?

Comment: Тут вопрос явно никак не относится к ExoPlayer. Куда файл потом отправляется? Кем отправляется? Может не отправлять его туда?

Comment: @kerradus, не-не-не, здесь даже не в этом дело, я в ручную указывал путь к файлу, который находится в корневой папке памяти телефона (ошибки в пути не может, множество раз все проверил). Для начала я просто пробовал работать с конкретным файлом без перемещения куда-либо, что понять, почему и как работает. Но результат безуспешный. На эмуляторах видео отображается, на реальных устройствах нет. Мне просто понять, в чем возможность ошибки, где я неправильно делаю. Permission все добавил, сделал все по инструкции, но пишет, что "Видео не может быть воспроизведено".

Comment: Если указывать Uri, получаемый из Intent. То все работает. Но, после перемещения у меня есть (пример того, что указано в вопросе), и по нему нужно воспроизвести видео, но ошибка. Вроде бы, все там элементарно, но...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить из абсолютного пути корректный Uri, необходимо использовать данный метод:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(absolutePath), null) { path, uri -> Log.d("myLog", "Uri = $uri") }
```

[Информация взята из этого ответа.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602986/convert-a-file-path-to-uri-in-android)